# WPF read an XML attribute

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, linq

Here is a an example of my XML file

```
<MyApp version="1.01">
   <MySettings>
      <Setting1>1</Setting1>
      <Setting2>2</Setting2>
   </MySettings>
 </MyApp>
```

I want to do a check on the version in the XML file.  Then if the version checks out look at the elements inside `MySettings.`  Trying to do it with LINQ but cannot figure it out.  Figured it would be something like;

```
var settings = (
            from x in myXML.Descendants("MyApp").Descendants("MySettings")
            where  (string)myXML.Descendants("MyApp").Attributes("version") == "1.0" 
            select new {...
```

Problem is that my where statement does not work.  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can navigate to desired section (depending to version) and get settings as dictionary using this snippet:

```
string xml = @"<MyApp version='1.01'>
   <MySettings>
      <Setting1>1</Setting1>
      <Setting2>2</Setting2>
   </MySettings>
 </MyApp>";
 var doc= XDocument.Parse(xml);
var settings = doc.Descendants("MyApp")
                  .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("version") == "1.0")
                  .Descendants("MySettings")
                  .Elements()
                  .ToDictionary(x => x.Name.ToString(), x => (string)x);
```

Return is:

```
Setting1 | 1 
Setting2 | 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for something like this:

```
myXML.Descendants("MyApp")
.Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("version") == "1.0")
.Select( ... );
```